# Spring batch, using subwriters with different commit intervals

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a spring batch job with this situation:

[STEP (commit-interval of 2500)]

- Reader: Do a query in a table and extract a combination of a PRODUCT_ID and Service.
- Processor:
  -- Queries all registers of Table A and Table B with this combination of Product_ID+Service and correct some fields. Finally, return corrected list of items to Writer.
- Writer:
  -- I have 3 writers inside it. I group the main list in all items that have a flag marked as true to inser, update, delete. I send the sublist to the correct writer.

My "problem" is that I see that in some cases, I am sending 68000~ items to the writer (with a commit-interval of 2500 and I am worried if in a future this can break the job.

I am searching a solution to limit this size to avoid memory problems but I am not sure if spring batch have options to work this type of situations.

I try making sublist inside my writer to make the commits in the "real" commit-interval, anyway, I can't imagine how to avoid this in the Processor.

Comment: With a commit-interval 2500 defined for the step you will never get more then 2500 items read, processed and written in one chunk. For the writer it will be even less. As you are using subset. The sum of items in 3 lists will be 2500.

Comment: Not really, in the processor I make a query to bbdd with the product+service combination, this can result in a number between 1-50 items by each combination. I send this collection to the writer so each combination can send until 50 items to writer. 2500 defined in reader but my writer updates until 50mil

Comment: I got it. I'm afraid Spring Batch is not suitable for your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chunk size is based on read items. If the processor creates more items, then Spring Batch cannot control this. It is up to you to handle that.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I have to limit the chunk size before read the elements in my step according to the num Items that I will generate after the processor executes. Thanks